# SQL - Finding rows with specific combination of values in a column

Tags: sql, subquery, window-functions

Not sure how to phrase this question precisely, it's probably best understood with an example. I've tried looking around on SO but could not quite find what I was looking for. Apologies if it exists, I'll be happy to close this one if so.

Working with a SQL database, my data looks like this:

```
col1 | col2
------------
A    |   11
A    |   56
A    |   59
B    |   56
C    |   59
C    |   56
```

I want to find the values of col1 that have got, in col2, values of 56 and 59 but not 11. So the query on the example table above would return only 'C'.

I have tried windowing and subqueries, if feels like it should not be too difficult, but not quite making it. Any tip is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "56 and 59 but not 11.", and you want A? I'd say C.

Comment: What if D has 56, 59 and 64? Should it be returned?

Comment: @jarlh you are right, sorry typed the wrong one, I meant 'C' not sure why 'A' came out! I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I like `group by` and `having` for this purpose:

```
select col1
from t
group by col1
having sum(case when col2 = 56 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when col2 = 59 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when col2 = 11 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

The `sum()` count each particular value.  Then `> 0` means that at least one row is present for the `col1` value and `= 0` means none is present.

Note:  This is based on your description of the problem.  This would return `'C'`, not `'A'`, which is consistent with the description.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `WHERE` clause to only include those 3 values when you do your `GROUP BY`. Use the `HAVING` clause to check that 56 is the `min()` value, i.e no value 11 present. Also check that 59 is the `max()` value, to make sure both 56 and 59 is there.

```
select col1
from t
where col2 in (11, 56, 59)
group by col1
having min(col2) = 56 and max(col2) = 59
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, this should work:

```
select a.col1 
from t as a 
where 
  a.col1 = 56   
  and not exists(select 1 from t as b 
    where b.col1 = a.col1
      and b.col1 = 11
 )
 and exists(select 1 from t as c 
    where c.col1 = a.col1
      and c.col1 = 59
 )
 group by a.col1 -- maybe you need to eliminate duplicates
```

To get a better answer, you may provide more details about the distributions:

- The combinations of col1 and col2 are unique.
- There are only these 3 different values in the table.